# I'm working on the Trailhead "using Date and Date/ time formulas" I believe that I have the formula right but I get the error

Tags: formula-field, trailhead

This is my error. Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong: 
The 'Day_of_the_Week__c' is not reporting the correct day of the week (Monday, Tuesday, etc.)

I see from some other threads that the problem is how Salesforce is reading the timezones. I've switched time zones in my dev org, but am unable to pass this exercise. My formula is working on Contacts. My formula is the same as others that say they have passed, and syntex is right. Does anyone know if there is another way around this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the formulas you are finding is they don't account for the date being stored in GMT and converted to the user's local timezone. For your formula to consistently pass, you should replace TODAY with the functions needed to get the date value of the TEXT of NOW.
The text of now will return the NOW datetime in GMT and then the date will be calculated without converting to the user's timezone. This will eliminate the timezone problem.